# Element ID in schedules using c# revit api

Tags: c#, revit-api

How to get Element ID in schedules with c# and revit API? similar to this video with Dynamo  - https://youtu.be/U-tVoCYilxo - but with c# and revit api.

When I execute my code, the third column doesn't appear and I get only two columns with width and height.

(I don't know what to write more - StackOverflow doesn't let me to post my issue without writing more text...)

here is my try:

```
using Autodesk.Revit.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.Revit.Attributes;
using Autodesk.Revit.DB;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI;
using Autodesk.Revit.UI.Selection;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Nice3point.Revit.Toolkit.External;
using Ecoworx.Core.Elements;

namespace Ecoworx
{
[Transaction(TransactionMode.Manual)]
public class CreateScheduleCommandHandler : ExternalEventHandler
{
public override void Execute(UIApplication uiapp)
{
UIDocument uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
Application app = uiapp.Application;
Document doc = uidoc.Document;

CreateSchedule(uiapp);
}

public static void CreateSchedule(UIApplication uiapp)
{
UIDocument uidoc = uiapp.ActiveUIDocument;
Application app = uiapp.Application;
Document doc = uidoc.Document;

using (Transaction t = new Transaction(doc, "Create single-category"))
{
t.Start();

// Create schedule
ViewSchedule vs = ViewSchedule.CreateSchedule(doc, new ElementId(BuiltInCategory.OST_Windows));

ElementId someId = new ElementId(BuiltInCategory.OST_Windows);

BuiltInParameter bip = (BuiltInParameter)(someId.IntegerValue);

doc.Regenerate();

// Add fields to the schedule
AddRegularFieldToSchedule(vs, new ElementId(BuiltInParameter.CASEWORK_WIDTH));
AddRegularFieldToSchedule(vs, new ElementId(BuiltInParameter.CASEWORK_HEIGHT));
AddRegularFieldToSchedule(vs, new ElementId(bip));

t.Commit();
}
}

public static void AddRegularFieldToSchedule(ViewSchedule schedule, ElementId paramId)
{
ScheduleDefinition definition = schedule.Definition;

// Find a matching SchedulableField
SchedulableField schedulableField =
definition.GetSchedulableFields().FirstOrDefault(sf => sf.ParameterId == paramId);

if (schedulableField != null)
{
// Add the found field
definition.AddField(schedulableField);
}
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to cast an `ElementId` to a `BuiltInParameter` and then back to an `ElementId`.

Doesn't passing the id directly solve the problem?
So like this:

```
ElementId someId = new ElementId(BuiltInCategory.OST_Windows);

doc.Regenerate();

// Add fields to the schedule
AddRegularFieldToSchedule(vs, new ElementId(BuiltInParameter.CASEWORK_WIDTH));
AddRegularFieldToSchedule(vs, new ElementId(BuiltInParameter.CASEWORK_HEIGHT));
AddRegularFieldToSchedule(vs, someId);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the `Element ID` of the `parameter` that will host the `Element ID` Property.

You have to get the `ElementId` of the parameter and then pass it into your method that shows the field in the schedule.